# getting errors when running "ionic serve"

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

My working environment is:

macOS

node  v6.9.1

npm   v3.10.8

ionic v2.1.14

I got these errors when I run `ionic serve` :

```
> ionic-app-base@ ionic:serve /Users/Hao/Project/OneCharacter
> ionic-app-scripts serve

module.js:597
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^

Error: dlopen(/Users/Hao/Project/OneCharacter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/Hao/Project/OneCharacter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-48/binding.node: truncated mach-o error: segment __TEXT extends to 1212416 which is past end of file 121392
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Hao/Project/OneCharacter/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:23:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "ionic:serve" "--"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-app-base@ ionic:serve: `ionic-app-scripts serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-app-base@ ionic:serve script 'ionic-app-scripts serve'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-app-base package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts serve
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-app-base
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-app-base
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Hao/Project/OneCharacter/npm-debug.log
There was an error serving your Ionic application: There was an error with the spawned command: serve
```

I have already run `npm install` in my project. It seems this is a problem about `node-sass`? Or maybe it is due to the bad network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bad network connection, then this is probably the problem. I faced a similar problem. "ionic serve" requires an internet connection to be executed properly.

Nevertheless, if this is not the case, try running the following command to serve your app in development mode:

```
npm run ionic:serve
```

I also suggest you to update your ionic CLI to a more stable version with the following command:

```
# May need "sudo"
npm install -g ionic@2.2.3
```

Comment: Ohhh... I forgot to close this question. But still thank you a lot! I think my problem is very likely due to the bad network (since I'm in China). Here is the possible solution for Chinese programmers: https://github.com/lmk123/blog/issues/28